# what is the correct way to concat strings in c++ and execute using system

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, stdstring

The following code is used in a native c++ library to create directory under android shell,

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xprea_lib_STB_mkdir(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jstring jdir) {
const char* dir = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(jdir, 0);    
string d=dir;
string cmd= "su -c 'mkdir -p "+d+"'";
const char* c=cmd.c_str();
LOGE("s%s",c);
system(c);

}
```

it's not working because the command is built from concatenated strings.
I tested it without concatenation and it's working

What is the correct way to concat the strings all together and send them to system()

Comment: why didn't you use sprintf ? ... what is logged by LOGE ?

Comment: What is the resulting string?

Comment: also: why you wana do this via c++? this code can be runned with java as well ... even if you really, really wana call system() from c++ then just concat the string in java

Comment: i went with c++ because want the code to be secure and not easily reverse engineered, the result string is su -c 'mkdir -p /sdcard/test' nothing is wrong with it :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your concatenation  `"su -c 'mkdir -p "+d+"'"` results in the string</strike>

`su -c 'mkdir -p BLA'` (If the dir name is BLA)

So the command `su` searches for a command named `mkdir -p BLA` which it won't find. Better make:

`"su -c mkdir -p '"+d+"'"` your concatenation. This way it will search for a command named `mkdir` which it hopefully will find, and the directory name may even contain white space (although you would have to escape the `'` and `\` character with `\`.

Comment: this will be executed under android shell, i have tested it, it doesn't need those extra ""

Comment: No it doesn't need the extra "". But the way you placed your `'` messes things up. You  turn `mkdir -p BLA` into a single string for the shell, and the `su` command tries to find a command with that name.

Comment: Mea culpa -- I'm wrong. `su` actually does remove `'` before parsing commands.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these 3 lines :

```
string d=dir;
string cmd= "su -c 'mkdir -p "+d+"'";
const char* c=cmd.c_str();
```

With these lines :

```
char cmd[1024];
sprintf(cmd,"su -c 'mkdir -p %s '",dir);
```

Comment: Well , can you please paste here , what issue you are facing. Is it error or system call not working ?

Comment: Can you paste output of const char* dir ,

Comment: it's "/sdcard/test" as sent from java

Comment: Then I dont think it's an issue of string concatination, I guess either you dont have access to create directory "/sdcard/test" or you are not running program as su.

Comment: if I can ask my question differently, how to make system call with parameters

Comment: Please refer this link for system function. whatever you can execture from shell , you can do same with system function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/